# How Secure is sourcing $HOME/.bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm new to linux/bash, and spent many weeks trying to solve how to enable a virtual appliance (linux/bash based) to automatically authenticate and execute a command on a network target.

I got it to work, but am new to linux and dont understand the security implications of what I wrote. Its a homelab, but I would like it to mimic good principles of device security.

My script is stored in /home/userX/bin/ as 'scriptX' and contains the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
source $HOME/.bashrc
source *commands to authenticate to target*
source *command to scan adapters*
```

This works when I'm logged into SSH and do ./ to run in an interactive environment. However, as a cron job, it wouldn't work until I sourced $HOME among some other things. I have a cron job setup like the following:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then inside the cron job

```
@reboot . /etc/skel/.bashrc ; bash -l -c '/home/UserX/bin/scriptX'
```

So it works as intended, but I mishmashed parts of scripts I found online until it worked.

Besides changing the account from root to a less privileged user, is there anything I could improve upon with how this operation is handeled?

Comment: You don't describe enough what is your overall goal. Tell a lot more about your "virtual appliance" and what you want to do with it

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 2):

Sourcing any file (e.g. `$HOME/.bashrc`) is as secure as what have been written in that file.

For an extreme example, if your `.bashrc` contains `/bin/rm -rf $HOME` it is *very* unsecure.

Notice that sourcing won't affect any *parent* shell.

Maybe you need to learn more about SSH and how to use it with public/private keys; read some SSH tutorial.

Comment: Do you think I should dig into more what parts of the bashrc environment made it work, or explore public/private keys and keep as is?

Comment: You need to learn both: shell scripting & SSH

Comment: Totally agree. But to accomplish not leaving the front door unlocked, so to speak, what do you think I should do first to tighten up the above script scenario? Implement a public key system, or clean up how the script was written?

Comment: You won't *implement* a public key system. You'll *use* one (and it is called `ssh`)